# executing a com addin function with a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a com addin I use for running analysis on systems. It is not listed in the AddIn block, but is loaded in the comAddIns. Is there a way I can execute the AddIn's functions via VBA? Using Excel 2010

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: This might help.  [How to use Excel VBA macros and COM add-ins in one solution](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/27/use-excel-vba-macros-addins/).  "In this article we’ll take a look at how you can access your Excel Add-in objects and functions from within a VBA routine as well as how to access VBA functions from within your Excel COM Add-in".

Comment: Also [this reference article from Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/automationaddins.aspx) could help too: "Using Automation Functions In VBA: The first step is to establish a reference to your automation add in."

Answer (score 1):

*Yes it's possible to execute Add-Ins through VBA. But I would like to suggest you few simple steps, help you to recover your COM Add-Ins.*

- Load Excel if not.
- Click the File command, hit Options.
- Find Add-Ins from the Menu.
- Check left bottom for Manage, then select Disabled Items and then
  Click Go.
- From pop-up windows find your add-ins, select it and click Enable.

**or**

- Click Manage button, and from the list select the COM Add-Ins then
  OK.
- From COM Add-Ins Pop up windows find your Add-Ins, select it and Finish with 
  OK.
- Finally Restart Excel.

**EDITED PART:**

*Inducded this part on OP's demand, since OP need to run Third Party Add-In, as mentioned in comments below, from VBA code.*

```
Private Declare Function XLLFunction Lib "C:\PathTo3rdPartyDLL\3rdParty.xll" (ByVal A as Integer, ByVal B as String, C as Double) As Double

Sub Function ThirdPartADDInRUN(A as Integer, B as String, C as Double) as Double
    ThirdPartADDInRUN = XLLFunction(A, B, C)
End Sub
```

**NB:** Specify the File Path & ADD-In name exactly as on your system drive.

Comment: Not sure why you got the down vote...this is a good solution to a vague question.

Comment: @jrichall thank, you have endorsed the answer. Have nice time.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. Sorry for the vague question. The addin is already running, and not disabled. I am just trying to call a function from that addin via VBA. The addin gives me a tab on the top of the sheet. I can click that tab, then execute a command from that tabs ribbon. I am wanting to execute that ribbon command from a VBA call.

Comment: @DButler,,this has created havoc,, "It is not listed in the AddIn block, but is loaded in the comAddIns". And upload the VBA code if any you have already tried, help me to fix the mistake.

Comment: OK, I'll try to explain. If I go to options-AddIns and select the COMAddins dropdown, I see the AddIn is there and checked. It places a tab on my excel sheet. When I want to run a parametric study, I click the tab, and click the "run Study" command from that tabs ribbon. So all is good with respect to the addin being there and functioning. I need help with how to call that "Run Study" command with VBA. I have no VBA code presently. I am new to VBA, and really have to fumble around with it to get it to work. I do not know how to call 3rd party AddIn commands with VBA.

Comment: To add to this, when I open VBA editor, should I see the AddIn listed on the left?

Comment: So your problem is, "how to call 3rd party AddIn commands with VBA ?", write!! Now I'm editing the current answer and including the code will help you to execute third party Add-In.

Comment: I think we are getting there. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: when I copy your code, I get a compile error, and the Function word is highlighted in the second line of code.

Comment: @RajeshS I cannot move this to chat. You can, if you would like. thank you!!!

Comment: @DButler, enter this code as Module. Let me say how. Right click Sheet Tab, find View Code click it. VBA Editor will open. On top left you find Project Explore windows. Select your Sheet and right click, find Insert then on Module just click, copy & paste this code, save and back Sheet  and Run it.